# Inserting multiple selection box values SQL

Tags: php, sql, database, multipleselection

```
<tr>
<td>Platform: </td>
<td><select multiple=\"multiple\" id=\"platform[]\" name=\"platform[]\" size=3>
            <option value=\"PC\">PC </option>
            <option value=\"PS4\">PS4 </option>
            <option value=\"Xbox One\">Xbox One </option>
            </select>   </td>
</tr>

    $artID= $_GET['artID'];

    $name2 = testinput($_POST['name']);
    $price2 = $_POST['price'];
    $VAT2 = testinput($_POST['VAT']);
    $description2 = testinput($_POST['description']);
    $beschrijving2 = testinput($_POST['beschrijving']);
    $foto2 = testinput($_POST['foto']);
    $genre2 = testinput($_POST['genre']);
    $platform2 = $_POST['platform'];


$sql = "UPDATE `producten` SET genre = \"$genre2\" , platform = \"$platform2\" , beschrijving=\"$beschrijving2\", description=\"$description2\", name = \"$name2\", price = \"$price2\", VAT = \"$VAT2\", foto = \"$foto2\" WHERE `artID` = $artID";
$qresult = $connect1 -> query($sql);
```

Here I'm trying to insert multiple selectionbox values into my database but the only value it returns in the database is "array" I'd like to insert them into the database with , between them preferably. I've tried looking up other solutions but I cant seem to find the right one for me.

Comment: You don't seem to have any opening PHP tags... I expected a `<?php` after your first row.

Comment: There is I just didnt copy paste the whole thing, my bad

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['platform']` is an array, so you'll need to decide how you want to store it. You can use `implode` to make a string out of the variables.

```
$platform2 = implode(',',$_POST['platform']); // becomes "PC,Xbox One"
```

As a side note, I'd really suggest binding your variables to prevent SQL injection.